# Request aborted when trying to post data from vue js to laravel backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have been struggling with an issue for like the whole day now. Every time I want to post data to my laravel back end from my vue js component, it says that the request has been aborted. I really can't see what's wrong with my code. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have CORS installed so that' not the problem. I have tried to clear the route cache and that didn't work either.

Controller store method. Here is where I make a check whether the title exists and if not, proceed to save the story in the database:

```
public function store(
    AuthenticatedUserId $authenticatedUserId,
    CreateNewRecordInDatabase $createNewRecordInDatabase,
    FindDataById $findDataById, 
    RetrieveAllData $retrieveAllData,
    Request $request, 
    $writer
    )
{
    $writer = $findDataById->findDataById(User::class, $writer);

    $stories = $retrieveAllData->retrieveAllData(Story::class);

    foreach ($stories as $check_title) {
        if ($check_title->title == $request->title) {
            return redirect()
                ->route('writer.create', ['writer' => $authenticatedUserId->authId()])
                ->with('title_exists', 'Title already exists');
        }
    }

    $createNewRecordInDatabase->createRecord($writer->stories(), [
        'title' => $request->title,
        'story' => $request->story,
        'published_on' => date('m-d-Y'),
        'category_id' => $request->category_id
    ]);

    return response()->json('success');
}
```

API route:

```
Route::post('/dashboard/writer/{writer}/store', 'Story\StoryController@store');
```

Vue component:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <input  v-model="title" type="text" 
                        class="input-field" 
                        placeholder="Give it a catchy title" 
                        required
                        >
                <label for="title">Give it a catchy title</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <select v-model="category_id" name="category_id">
                     <option 
                        v-for="category in categories"
                        v-bind:key="category.id"
                        v-bind:value="category.id"
                        >{{ category.category }}
                     </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="white col s12" id="editorjs"></div>

        <div class="col s12">
            <button @click="publishStory" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Publish</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

```
<script>

import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
import Header from '@editorjs/header';
import Link from '@editorjs/link';
import List from '@editorjs/list';
import Quote from '@editorjs/quote';

export default {
    props: ['categories', 'writer'],
    data() {
        return  {
            title: null,
            category_id: null,
            story: [],
            editor: new EditorJS({
                tools: {
                    header: {
                        class: Header,
                        inlineToolbar: true
                    }, 
                    list: {
                        class: List,
                        inlineToolbar: true
                    }, 
                    link: {
                        class: Link,
                        inlineToolbar: true
                    },
                    quote: {
                        class: Quote,
                        inlineToolbar: true
                    }
                }
            }),
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
        }
    },
    methods: {
        publishStory() {
            this.editor.save()
            .then(outputData => this.story = outputData.blocks)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/dashboard/writer/${this.writer}/store`, {
                    title: this.title,  
                    story: this.story,
                    category_id: this.category_id,
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

    },
    mounted() {}
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you checked if the request hit the the right route ?

Comment: check your network tab in browser dev tools. there is usually an error in the response

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI no, I didn't. How do I do that?

Comment: inspect network tab and see request response

Comment: @JoshKisb the only I see is a source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Source Map URL: popper.js.map

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI the response I see from app.js (which renders vuejs) has a status code of 200, though there is this message: "Response has been truncated" in my mozilla dev tools. If I undersand correctly, this means my request is to big? size is 1.65 mb... everything else is status code 200

Comment: @SulejmanLimaj i guess so check your php.ini settings

Comment: try commenting your route controller, and just return a json, maybe just return `{"success":true}`, and see what you get. if it got the correct value, then it might be your controller is running a long process, if it got wrong value, then you might be contacting a wrong route

Comment: @SulejmanLimaj when checking for errors you check the one corresponding to the url in question. in this case it would be the writer store url. but usually if there was a proper error it would be red

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase php.ini settings

```
max_input_time 
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size   
memory_limit
max_input_vars
```

[PHP Truncating POST Data](https://dan.hersam.com/2015/02/17/php-truncating-post-data/)

Comment: Went through the article, did those things, nothing at all. Am gonna contact a mentor on codemnetor.io, see whether he/she can help. Cause this thing is making me question reality itself let alone my abilities :p. Thank you for trying...

Comment: did you restarted your web server ? after editing your php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing the `<form>` tag to `<div>` tag worked for me.